# How can I "get" the data from a sqlite3 database and store them as variables?

Tags: python, select, sqlite

I am trying to query whether the staff ID and password are correct. The query works, however I want to get the fname and lname data from the database and print certain fields. It seems as though the row[fname] and row[lname] doesn't work... is there another way to do this? I keeps saying fname is not defined.

```
    import sqlite3

    connection = sqlite3.connect('shop.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    create_table = '''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
    staff_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    password CHAR(4),
    fname VARCHAR(20),
    lname VARCHAR(30));'''
    cursor.execute(create_table)

    staffid = input('staff id: ')
    password = input('password: ')
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM employee WHERE staff_ID=? AND password=?', [staffid, password])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row != None:
        print(row[fname]+' '+row[lname])
```

You may insert any values into this table, I just didn't want the code to look too bulky... Thanks!

Comment: Just figured it out...

Comment: It uses indexing rather than field name referencing. For example, row[fname] should be row[2].

Comment: print(row[2]+' '+row[3])